# Provide log files on jenkins pipeline job result page

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline job which runs a test. During the tests server logs are created. I can download the server logs into the workspace.

Can I somehow put these server logs into the result page of the job so that developers can analyze them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `archive` basic step to archive your logs. It will show a link in the build page.

See [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#archive-archive-artifacts)